# Possible to use the same Google accounts on 2 exact same phones?

Tags: google-account, multiple-devices

I'm trying to find out if I can use my Google accounts on 2 exact mobile phones?

I've only been able to find that you can use Google accounts on multiple devices, but can the devices be the same make & model?

Comment: Two mobile phones are never "exact the same" because each phone has a unique IMEI and other serial numbers.

Comment: Obviously the same model phone is what I was referring too!

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, it is possible to use the same Google account on 2 exact same phones, even both same make and model.**

No specific source or reference, but Google doesn't really put any restrictions on how their account is used on Android, including on many Android emulators having the "same" make and model.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently you can't use the play store on both of then. I have two of the same device and the play store only recognizes one of them. The play store won't even let me install the store. I had to stop the ad blockers on chrome browser and use the link to the play store app.Then I found only one listed.

Comment: This is not true and never has been since Android 4, for me anyway.

Comment: Looks like there's an issue with one of your device, though the detail is currently lacking. Like, have you logged in the same Google account on the other device? Also, looks like you're talking about the Play Store website. Note that Play Store app cannot be installed from any stores; it needs to be flashed (along with few Google services as a bare minimum) for it to work properly.